# What are current pitfalls of using LuaTeX over pdfTeX

Tags: bibtex, pstricks, luatex

I know that there are several closely related older posts about LuaTeX.

- [Using LuaTeX as a replecment for pdfTeX 3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32295/using-luatex-as-a-replacement-for-pdftex)
- [LuaLaTeX and PSTricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99724/lualatex-and-pstricks)
- [Migrating from pdfTeX to LuaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65480/migrating-from-pdftex-to-luatex-problems-with-reproducing-output-for-legacy-pro)

As of recently I started entertaining the idea of switching my default engine form pdfTeX to LuaTeX. The main upshot as I see naively right now is the direct availability of a powerful scripting language from within my latex documents. That is related to my older questions about automatic document update as well as embedding animations into the presentation.

Before I make a leap of the faith I would like to know the current pitfalls of using LuaTeX
over pdfTeX. How do people use PSTricks with LuaTeX? Any issues with Powerdot class? Are there any issues with bibtex or even commonly used packages for math publications?

Edit: I am still goofing off in front of the computer and testing LuaTeX engine. I tried on several complex documents with figures, bibliography files and similar. Works like a charm
with the usual workflow for PSTricks

```
lualatex --output-format=dvi file.tex -> dvips file.dvi -> ps2pdf file.ps
```

I think I am going to edit my **.profile** and switch to lualatex unless I encounter a major problem.

Comment: It is possible to use PSTricks with the `auto-pst-pdf` package.  See this thread for some discussion: [Using PSTricks with Lua](http://tug.org/mailman/htdig/pstricks/2012/009516.html). I don't know if this is a drop-in solution, however.

Comment: @Alan Munn Thanks for a quick replay! I saw that post but auto-pst-pdf didn't work for me (I confess I tried only for a minute) but see my edit about output format. I think I am a happy camper now. I just plotted a circle and did some arithmetics in Lua in the same document. Bibliography works like a charm!

Comment: The `dvi to ps`-route will not work if you use system and open type fonts through `fontspec`. And you should be aware that inputenc doesn't work with luatex and so you should avoid to use non-ascii chars in the source.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I don't think this is a duplicate. Predrag has already listed the question you linked to in his question, and he specifically wants to know about PSTricks compatibility, which that question doesn't really discuss.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Thanks for quick pointers. I appreciate your contribution to the community! In spite of my name I write almost always only in English so non-ascii is not an issue for me. I do not often play with fonts so that was also secondary issue for me. My main concern is interoperability with things that I do use like PSTricks, Powerdot, BibTeX and most commonly used math packages.